# Problems installing astra toolbox in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to install [astra-toolbox](https://pypi.org/project/astra-toolbox/) for python on windows and I'm getting this error.

Anyone have any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

i have tried to install via `pip` method  but it's not working facing the same error as you. if you go to official installation documentation [instructions](https://astra-toolbox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/install.html) no method to use `pip` method is given.
i have `anaconda` installed in my system so i have tried using these commands [source](https://anaconda.org/astra-toolbox/astra-toolbox):
`conda install -c astra-toolbox astra-toolbox`
`conda install -c astra-toolbox/label/dev astra-toolbox`

this solve the  issue and astra-toolbox is installed in my system. 
PS. this will downgrade package in anaconda. so better to install in separate python environment.